# Add css to tooltip in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

everyone! I'm trying to change default tooltip to red one in fullcalendar. I'm using bootstrap, but as far as I understand, the tooltip that I see is a Windows one(white rectangle). How can I change that?
This is how I call tooltip:

```
eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $(this).find(".fc-content").attr({ 
        "data-toggle": "tooltip", 
        "title": calEvent.title, 
        "data-content": calEvent.title, 
        "data-container": "body" 
    }).addClass("red-tooltip");
    $(this).find(".fc-content").mouseover(function () { 
        $(this).tooltip('show'); 
    }, function () { 
        $(this).tooltip('hide'); 
    });
}
```

This is my CSS

```css
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { 
    border-bottom-color:#f00; 
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That's not how the `mouseover` event works. I think you meant to use `hover()`.

Comment: `mouseover` and `over` works fine, but I still can't change the view of tooltip.